# EXCEL: How to combine values from two different column into one new column on different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i am stuck with my procject again... I tried with formulas but i can t make it work or i can t make it right, and i couldn t find similar topic any where, here is the problem. As u can see in screenshot in this link https://ibb.co/FJRBxcM i have 2 worksheets, Sheet1 with some value generator, and Sheet"RadniNalog" where i copy&paste manualy certan values from Sheet1. My goal is to make it work automatically, when i paste data from another Workbook, as shown in screenshot example, i polulate range "A10:C27", range width is constant, always 3 column, but rows can change so number is X. Now i need values from "A10:A27" to copy to next empty column from left to right in Sheet"RadniNalog" from cells in 2nd row. Next i also need to copy Value from cell =F$13$ into the first row in sheet "RadniNalog" (on screenshot example its cell "E1" and that value from F13 needs to act like a Header for values belove it. If Value from header is the same as value in cell "F13" i need to continue adding values under existing ones, and if not move to the next available column. In screenshot example, if cell "D1" from sheet "RandiNalog" is same as cell "F13" in Sheet1, then values from range "A10:A27" should be added under last value in ColumnD. I need some VBA code if possible to make it work as wanted. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try by your own?

Comment: I tried with Vlookup and Hlookup + (match&row), but i only can get range from A10:A27 where i want it when i manualy type header value.  I don t know coding very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this code to **Sheet1** module

This code runs the macro **copyValuesToWs** when you put the code in **F13**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F13:G13")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call copyValuesToWs
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Create a new module** and insert this code

```
Option Explicit
 
Function FindLastRow(ByVal Col As Byte, ws As Worksheet) As Long
    FindLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function FindLastColumn(ByVal rw As Byte, ws As Worksheet) As Long
    FindLastColumn = ws.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function

Sub copyValuesToWs()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Radni nalog")
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Dim dstRng As Range
    Dim hdRng As Range
    
    ' Next row after ID
    Dim idRng As Range: Set idRng = ws1.Range("A10")
    
    ' find last row value in column A
    lRow = FindLastRow(1, ws1)
    
    ' range to be copied
    Set srcRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(idRng.Row, 1), ws1.Cells(lRow, 1))
    
    ' find last used column in sheet2
    lCol = FindLastColumn(1, ws2)
    
    ' header range
    Set hdRng = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(1, lCol))
    
    ' check if value exists in header
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sValue As Double: sValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws1.Range("F13").Value, hdRng, 0)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then  ' value exists
        ' find last row
        Set dstRng = ws2.Cells(FindLastRow(sValue, ws2) + 1, sValue)
        ' paste values
        srcRng.Copy
        dstRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
        ' set destination range
        Set dstRng = ws2.Cells(2, lCol + 1)
        
        ' set header value
        ws1.Range("F13:G13").Copy
        ws2.Cells(1, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        ' paste values
        srcRng.Copy
        dstRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```